# Why does scapy not like colons?

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to edit a packet in scapy and I'm getting an error when I try to define a MAC address, any ideas?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em5o7.png)

Comment: [ask]: "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: You need to put the address in quotes.